# Should Nginx and Flask run in the same container

Tags: docker, nginx, flask

The ideal is to have one process per container, but there is a strong affinity between **Flask+uwsgi** and **Nginx**.

Currently we run them together, but should we refactor ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a good idea to refactor. Try to make service ephemeral and run only one main process in it. So, in the end, you need to have something like this:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  web:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app/
    env_file:
      - common.env
  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: nginx:1.18-alpine
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./deployment/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./deployment/config.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\";'"
    depends_on:
      - web
```

It's designed to have only one main process in a container, in that case if your application fails the container will be down.